# Does Git use SHA-256 to calculate commit hashes?

Tags: git, sha256

Does the current version of git (2.30.0) already use SHA256 to calculate commit hashes by default?

If not, how can SHA-256 be enabled for a new git repository and how can be checked whether a certain git repository uses SHA-256 or SHA-1 for its commit hashes?

Comment: @mkrieger1 unfortunately no. I have seen multiple documents and articles regarding this move from 2017. but it's 2021 now, my question is whether this is now enabled by default and if not, how to use it?

Comment: But why? ......

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk because SHA-1 isn't really that secure anymore - so if you wanna use the commit hash to prove integrity for example, SHA-1 wouldn't be considered secure anymore in many contexts.

Comment: You might note that all constructed hashcode collisions in ever-considered-secure hashes are in .pdf's (and perhaps similar formats, but I think they're all .pdf's). That's because humans don't look at .pdf's directly, they look at a rendering, and you can hide a colossal amount of bullshit in a .pdf. The sort that it takes to steer a good hash code into producing a collision. Anybody trying to produce two snapshots that both looks sensible to a human eye has a much, *much* more daunting task in front of them.

Comment: Agreed - but there is sometimes legislation that puts requirements on cryptographic securit.
In particular, I would like to proof that commits existed at a cetain time by timestamping them using a (govenmentally trusted) TSA and the corresponding legislation that defines what is trusted specifies that hashes must be at least SHA-256

Comment: That's completely false.  Signing commits or tags relies on SHA-1 for security with the Merkle tree.

Comment: @Chris "signing a commit" means signing its hash. If you sing a SHA-1 hash to prove something and certain rules require for hash based proves at least SHA-256, then that won't work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Whether to use SHA-1 or SHA-256 is a per-repository setting in recent versions of Git.  The plan is eventually to make it possible to store data in a repository in SHA-256 and access the objects with either the SHA-1 name or the SHA-256 name.  SHA-1 remains the default.

Do note that the SHA-256 mode is experimental and could theoretically change but there are no plans to do so.  The Git developers are making every effort to not break compatibility with existing SHA-256 repositories.

To create a new repository with SHA-256, use the `--object-format` option to `git init`.  If you want to know which algorithm a *local* repository uses, run `git rev-parse --show-object-format`, which will output either `sha1` or `sha256`.  To see the hash of a *remote* repository, you can use `git ls-remote` and verify the length of the hashes printed.

Do note that no major forges support SHA-256 and therefore such repositories cannot be uploaded to them.

Comment: Thank you! this is very relevant information. Do you know whether there is any ETA on when to make this  feature non-experimental on git and when it might be supported by github? This seems to be a feature that's cooking already for quite a while

Comment: I'm the primary person working on it on the Git side and it happens in my free time, so it's hard to say.  Interoperability is coming, but the work is slow.  As for GitHub, I can't speak to the product roadmap.  If you want to see it (especially if you're a corporate user), let GitHub Support know, since GitHub tracks customer feedback and feature requests.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [man page for `git-init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) for version 2.30.0, the sha-256 support is still considered experimental:

```
--object-format=<format

    Specify the given object format (hash algorithm) for the
    repository. The valid values are sha1 and (if enabled) sha256.
    sha1 is the default.

    THIS OPTION IS EXPERIMENTAL! SHA-256 support is experimental and
    still in an early stage. A SHA-256 repository will in general not
    be able to share work with "regular" SHA-1 repositories. It should
    be assumed that, e.g., Git internal file formats in relation to
    SHA-256 repositories may change in backwards-incompatible ways.
    Only use --object-format=sha256 for testing purposes.
```

Comment: worked for me `mkdir sha256 && cd sha256` `git init --object-format=sha256` `dd if=/dev/zero bs=$((1024*1024)) count=$((5*1024)) | git hash-object --stdin --literally` result `dc18ca621300c8d3cfa505a275641ebab00de189859e022a975056882d313e64`, on WSL Ubuntu `git version 2.33.1`

Answer (score 8):

> According to the man page for git-init for version 2.30.0, the sha-256 support is still considered experimental:

Actually, Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) tones down the warning on SHA-256 repositories being an experimental curiosity.
There is no support (yet) for them to interoperate with traditional SHA-1 repositories, but at this point, there is no plan to make breaking changes to SHA-256 repositories and there is no longer need for such a strongly phrased warning.

See [commit 8e42eb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e42eb0e9ae44f65c360cd95ce28e84496ad8247) (31 Jul 2023) by [Adam Majer (`AdamMajer`)](https://github.com/AdamMajer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e48d9c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e48d9c78cc00805660b83ac809188d0c413e4c46), 07 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e42eb0e9ae44f65c360cd95ce28e84496ad8247): sha256 is no longer experimental
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Adam Majer</sup>

> Remove scary wording that basically stops people using sha256 repositories not because of interoperability issues with sha1 repositories, but from fear that their work will suddenly become incompatible in some future version of git.
>
> We should be clear that currently sha256 repositories will not work with sha1 repositories but stop the scary words.

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8e42eb0e9ae44f65c360cd95ce28e84496ad8247/Documentation/git.txt#L556-L557):

> is always used. The default is "sha1".
> See `--object-format` in [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init).

`object-format-disclaimer` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8e42eb0e9ae44f65c360cd95ce28e84496ad8247/Documentation/object-format-disclaimer.txt#L1-L9):

> Note: At present, there is no interoperability between SHA-256
> repositories and SHA-1 repositories.
>
> Historically, we warned that SHA-256 repositories may later need
> backward incompatible changes when we introduce such interoperability
> features. Today, we only expect compatible changes. Furthermore, if such
> changes prove to be necessary, it can be expected that SHA-256 repositories
> created with today's Git will be usable by future versions of Git
> without data loss.

---

Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), adds more details about the SHA-256 hash: the "streaming" interface used for bulk-checkin codepath has been narrowed to take only blob objects for now, with no real loss of functionality.

See [commit 9eb5419](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9eb5419799f08402ee3bd185c2d2c50ded669b06) (26 Sep 2023) by [Eric W. Biederman (`ebiederm`)](https://github.com/ebiederm).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3df51ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3df51ea0a5ef88b801ab30ca28f159b898183926), 10 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`bulk-checkin`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9eb5419799f08402ee3bd185c2d2c50ded669b06): only support blobs in `index_bulk_checkin`
>
> <sup>Inspired-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: "Eric W. Biederman"</sup>

> As the code is written today `index_bulk_checkin` only accepts blobs.
> Remove the enum `object_type` parameter and rename `index_bulk_checkin` to `index_blob_bulk_checkin,` `index_stream` to `index_blob_stream,` `deflate_to_pack` to `deflate_blob_to_pack,` `stream_to_pack` to `stream_blob_to_pack,` to make this explicit.
>
> Not supporting commits, tags, or trees has no downside as it is not currently supported now, and commits, tags, and trees being smaller by design do not have the problem that the problem that `index_bulk_checkin` was built to solve.
>
> Before we start adding code to support the hash function transition supporting additional objects types in `index_bulk_checkin` has no real additional cost, just an extra function parameter to know what the object type is.
> Once we begin the hash function transition this is not the case.
>
> The hash function transition document specifies that a repository with `compatObjectFormat` enabled will compute and store both the SHA-1 and SHA-256 hash of every object in the repository.
>
> What makes this a challenge is that it is not just an additional hash over the same object.
> Instead the hash function transition document specifies that the compatibility hash (specified with `compatObjectFormat`) be computed over the equivalent object that another git repository whose storage hash (specified with objectFormat) would store.
> When comparing equivalent repositories built with different storage hash functions, the oids embedded in objects used to refer to other objects differ and the location of signatures within objects differ.
>
> As blob objects have neither oids referring to other objects nor stored signatures their storage hash and their compatibility hash are computed over the same object.
>
> The other kinds of objects: trees, commits, and tags, all store oids referring to other objects.
> Signatures are stored in commit and tag objects.
> As oids and the tags to store signatures are not the same size in repositories built with different storage hashes the size of the equivalent objects are also different.
>
> A version of `index_bulk_checkin` that supports more than just blobs when computing both the SHA-1 and the SHA-256 of every object added would need a different, and more expensive structure.
> The structure is more expensive because it would be required to temporarily buffering the equivalent object the compatibility hash needs to be computed over.
>
> A temporary object is needed, because before a hash over an object can computed it's object header needs to be computed.
> One of the members of the object header is the entire size of the object.
> To know the size of an equivalent object an entire pass over the original object needs to be made, as trees, commits, and tags are composed of a variable number of variable sized pieces.
> Unfortunately there is no formula to compute the size of an equivalent object from just the size of the original object.
>
> Avoid all of those future complications by limiting `index_bulk_checkin` to only work on blobs.